# Data Pipeline error on a template from RDS to S3 copy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using the template to do a copy. In the "S3" data node, I have configured Custom format because my column data contains "comma".

The custom data format I am using has the following properties

Column seperator " is PIPE ("|") and Record seperator is "\n"

When I run the pipeline data does not get loaded into S3 and gives me the following error

Error copying record\nCause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException\nCause: null\nCause: Quote character must be defined in record format

Anyone faced this problem.

Answer (score 4):

"Escape Char" option is not shown under "Custom" format type in AWS Data pipeline

You can use "TSV" type as your custom format type and provide:

- "Column separator" as pipe(|),
- "Record separator" as new line(\n),
- "Escape Char" as backslash(\) or any other character you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Aurora as source database, I suggest you use [SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html) command. Otherwise, build your own using EMR (hive and sqoop projects will help you with this).